# getting an error in selenium using java with mySQL: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver, sql

```
package SeleWeb;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.sql.*;


 public class seldata 

 {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 

    {

   Connection connection;
   Statement statement;
   ResultSet rs;

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   String dbaseURL = "http://localhost:3306/selenium";
   driver.get(dbaseURL);
   String user = "root";
   String password = "";
   connection = null;
   try {    
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           System.out.println("Connecting to Database...");
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbaseURL, user, password);

           //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("dbaseURL","root","");
           System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
           if (connection != null) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connected to the Database...");
                try {
                        String query = "select * from employee";
                        statement = connection.createStatement();
                        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

                        while(rs.next()){
                            int EmpId= rs.getInt("EmpId");
                            String EmpName= rs.getString("EmpName");
                            String EmpAddress=rs.getString(3);
                            String EmpDept=rs.getString("EmpDept");
                            Double EmpSal= rs.getDouble(5);
                            System.out.println(EmpId+"\t"+EmpName+"\t"+EmpAddress+"\t"+EmpSal+"\t"+EmpDept);
                      }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) 
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

            }catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

               }


     }
```

Comment: Which JARs you have imported to project for database connection?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Comment: Can you please use latest JAR from here : https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&

Comment: not worked, same error reproduces

Comment: You need to check if your jar matches with the mysql(variant) you are trying to connect with.

Comment: Have you verified the jar is on your classpath? Try using an import statement of `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;` to verify it made it onto your classpath properly.

Comment: Please paste the exact error here, the full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this exception occurs when the JDBC URL is wrong and not accepted by loaded drivers. You should have the jar files in the classpath.
Also Try using JDBC driver specific URI prefix, which is `jdbc:mysql://` for MySQL. I mean defining

```
String dbaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/selenium";
```

instead of

```
String dbaseURL = "http://localhost:3306/selenium";
```